# How do i set the key value after unset the array value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array like below,

```
Array
(
    [14289] => Array
        (
            [0] => Karthikeyan
            [1] => Mathi
            [2] => RAvi
        )

    [14279] => Array
        (
            [0] => Karthikeyan
            [1] => Mathi
            [2] => RAvi
        )

    [14288] => Array
        (
            [0] => Karthikeyan
        )

    [14291] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mathi
        )

    [14284] => Array
        (
            [0] => RAvi
        )

)
```

if I unset the index[1] value from [14289] this one. after that the array display like below,

```
Array
(
    [14289] => Array
        (
            [0] => Karthikeyan
            [2] => RAvi
        )

    [14279] => Array
        (
            [0] => Karthikeyan
            [1] => Mathi
            [2] => RAvi
        )

    [14288] => Array
        (
            [0] => Karthikeyan
        )

    [14291] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mathi
        )

    [14284] => Array
        (
            [0] => RAvi
        )

)
```

But I need [14289] values like below,

```
Array
(
    [14289] => Array
        (
            [0] => Karthikeyan
            [1] => RAvi
        )
........
```

the key value should be [1] not [2]. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after

```
unset $example_array[14289][1];
```

do

```
$example_array[14289]= array_values($example_array[14289]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) on the array.